# Satellite data between 1975-1985 in Brazil?

Tags: data, imagery, satellite, brazil

So I've been looking for satellite imagery to use for a project without any luck. I need images between 1975 and 1985 near the Roosevelt river in Brazil, from any satellite at any spatial/spectral resolution (could be aerial also!).

I've checked USGS Earth Explorer and there are only 4 images from Landsat 2 and Landsat 4, and they're all cloudy.

So I was just curious if anybody knew of a satellite/aerial imagery source that was flying around at that time.

Comment: Have you tried military?

Comment: I found some military stuff from the 1960s but not the date range I'm looking for

Comment: Try looking for a GIS website for the state of Mato Grosso or the state of Rondonia.

Comment: There are data derived from [Projeto Radam](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projeto_Radambrasil). They are available [here](http://mapas.ibge.gov.br/bases-e-referenciais/bases-cartograficas/cartas.html). But good luck digging what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but if anyone else comes across this question, INPE have a lot of the Landsat archive over South America as far back as 1972: http://www.dgi.inpe.br/CDSR/